# Issue with a vb.net panel control loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a loop in vb.net where I am wanting to display 50 panels, all with the same 3 controls.  Only the last control is populated with the 3 controls, why is this?

```
    Dim PanelVerticalPoint As Integer = btDF.Height * 6

    For counter = 1 To 50 Step +1

        Dim ButtonPanel As Panel = New Panel


        With ButtonPanel

            ButtonPanel.Location = New Point(0, PanelVerticalPoint)
            ButtonPanel.Size = New Size(btDF.Width, btDF.Height)
            Me.Controls.Add(ButtonPanel)

            ButtonPanel.Controls.Add(btCustomButtonMenu)
            ButtonPanel.Controls.Add(btCustomTextBox)
            ButtonPanel.Controls.Add(btCustomButton)

        End With


        PanelVerticalPoint = PanelVerticalPoint + btDF.Height


    Next counter
```

Comment: Why not use a custom control for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a new instance of the buttons to each panel. You are adding the same button instance to the panels so each add is really moving the button.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense now.  But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to clone a control. It looks like your case might be appropriate for a user control instead. Make the user control in the designer with the buttons and text box, then just create many instances of the user control instead of the panel.

Here's a very similar question with that kind of answer
[Clone Winform control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201341/clone-winform-control/)

Comment: I think this is the path I will take.  I think I am almost finished, but for some reason I cannot see any of the controls on the user control when I add it to my main form.  Any thoughts?  Thank you for the help!